# How exactly is GLSL's "coherent" memory qualifier interpreted by GPU drivers for multi-pass rendering?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, multipass

The GLSL specification states, for the "coherent" memory qualifier: *"memory variable where reads and writes are coherent with reads and writes from other shader invocations"*.

In practice, I'm unsure how this is interpreted by modern-day GPU drivers with regards to multiple rendering passes. When the GLSL spec states "other shader invocations", does that refer to shader invocations running only during the current pass, or any possible shader invocations in past or future passes? For my purposes, I define a pass as a **"glBindFramebuffer-glViewPort-glUseProgram-glDrawABC-glDrawXYZ-glDraw123"** cycle; where I'm currently executing 2 such passes per "render loop iteration" but may have more per iteration later on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When the GLSL spec states "other shader invocations", does that refer to shader invocations running only during the current pass, or any possible shader invocations in past or future passes?

It means exactly what it says: "other shader invocations". It could be the same program code. It could be different code. It doesn't matter: shader invocations that aren't this one.

Normally, OpenGL handles synchronization for you, because OpenGL can track this fairly easily. If you map a range of a buffer object, modify it, and unmap it, OpenGL knows how much stuff you've (potentially) changed. If you use glTexSubImage2D, it knows how much stuff you changed. If you do transform feedback, it can know exactly how much data was written to the buffer.

If you do transform feedback into a buffer, then bind it as a source for vertex data, OpenGL knows that this will stall the pipeline. That it must wait until the transform feedback has completed, and then clear some caches in order to use the buffer for vertex data.

When you're dealing with image load/store, you *lose all of this*. Because so much could be written in a completely random, unknown, and unknowable fashion, OpenGL generally plays really loose with the rules in order to allow you flexibility to get the maximum possible performance. This triggers a lot of undefined behavior.

In general, the only rules you can follow are those outlined in section 2.11.13 of the OpenGL 4.2 specification. The biggest one (for shader-to-shader talk) is the rule on stages. If you're in a fragment shader, it is safe to assume that the vertex shader(s) that specifically computed the point/line/triangle for *your triangle* have completed. Therefore, you can freely load values that were stored by them. But *only from the ones that made you*.

Your shaders cannot make assumptions that shaders executed in previous rendering commands have completed (I know that sounds odd, given what was just said, but remember: "only from the ones that made you"). Your shaders cannot make assumptions that other invocations of the same shader, using the same uniforms, images, textures, etc, in the same rendering command have completed, except where the above applies.

The only thing you can assume is that writes your shader instance itself made are visible... to itself. So if you do an `imageStore` and do an `imageLoad` to the same memory location *through the same variable*, then you are guaranteed to get the same value back.

Well, unless someone else wrote to it in the meantime.

Your shaders cannot assume that a later rendering command will *certainly* fetch values written (via image store or atomic updates) by a previous one. **No matter how much later!** It doesn't matter what you've bound to the context. It doesn't matter what you've uploaded or downloaded (technically. Odds are you'll get correct behavior in some cases, but undefined behavior is still *undefined*).

If you need that guarantee, if you need to issue a rendering command that will fetch values written by image store/atomic updates, you must explicitly ask synchronize memory sometime after issuing the writing call and before issuing the reading call. This is done with [`glMemoryBarrier`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMemoryBarrier).

Therefore, if you render something that does image storing, you *cannot* render something that uses the stored data until an appropriate barrier has been sent (either explicitly in the shader or explicitly in OpenGL code). This could be an image load operation. But it could be rendering from a buffer object written by shader code. It could be a texture fetch. It could be doing blending to an image attached to the FBO. It doesn't matter; you can't do it.

Note that this applies for *all* operations that deal with image load/store/atomic, not just shader operations. So if you use image store to write to an image, you won't necessarily read the right data unless you use a `GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT​` barrier.

Comment: Many thanks for those very detailed in-depth insights. image_load_store to allow shaders to write stuff is fairly new so those exact warnings are precisely what I've been missing when reading around the net. Much appreciated! In practice, my 2nd frag shader reads what my 1st frag shader wrote, so sounds like I'll have to have a single glMemoryBarrier call between those two passes.

Comment: Hmm....  OR I could just specify coherent/volatile, from what I understand, memory barrier or not -- but since the 1st (producer) shader is writeonly and the 2nd (consumer) shader is readonly, not specifying any memory qualifier and putting a single barrier in between the 2 shaders might be more efficient?

Comment: @PhilS.: No. Specifying `coherent` *will not help*. `coherent` does not guarantee ordering. `coherent` means that caching is turned off, so that `coherent` writes become visible to other `coherent` reads. It doesn't affect the *order* of completion; only a barrier does that. And since you need a barrier anyway, you don't need `coherent` at all. Indeed, you should only use `coherent` if the ordering is implicit (ie: you're reading from data that was written by your direct producing shader).

Comment: @PhilS.: I made a correction to the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, from the specs I figured that for my specific 2-shader use-cases I'll need at least gl.ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT | gl.FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT | gl.SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | gl.TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT | gl.TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT -- thanks again!  =)